# How to save file as cdr without Corel Draw

Tags: adobe-illustrator, coreldraw

I need to have project in **.cdr format** but I don't have Corel Draw. Is there any way (like for example convertion .ai (Illustrator) file to .cdr) to get .cdr file?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: probably more suited for http://superuser.com/

Comment: I think best way save as each page as .svg or .svgz, then use import in Corel Draw.

Answer (score 2):

Export from Illustrator as .WMF (Windows Meta File). 
Use CorelDraw to import the the .WMF with everything intact except filters.

Answer (score 0):

Save as .eps file. The eps format can be opened in CorelDraw. Make sure to convert all text objects to curves.